# How to hide certain elements using ng-hide?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework

I'am making an android app for my wordpress blog using ionic, I successfully loaded posts from my site using json data. I used ng-hide on a check box for each post and when I check it hides the particular post. But what I need is to keep the checked post and hide every other post.
Help me here.! Thankyou.!

Here's my code:

```html
<div class="card" ng-repeat="story in stories | filter:searchbox" ng-hide="hidePost">
  <div class="item">
    <h1>{{story.title.rendered}}</h1> 
  </div>
  <div class="item item-body">
    <p ng-bind-html="story.content.rendered" ng-href="{{story.content.rendered}}" style="width:200px;">{{story.content.rendered}}</p>

  </div>
  <div class="item item-divider">
    <ion-checkbox ng-model="hidePost">Hide</ion-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce a plunker so that we can help you in better way

Comment: or at least show your controller.. is hidePost just a boolean, and will showPosty just be a boolean?

Comment: I didn't use a controller for show/hide, I used it just to get data from wordpress site. Thats why I did't include js code.